# Django app rendering poorly after deployment

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, uvicorn

I just deployed my django app to my custom domain. I'm using Nginx as the web server and Uvicorn for ASGI. Static files are stored in an AWS S3 bucket. The Django application is deployed on an EC2 instance. However my styling for mydomain.com/app is messed up. All my other apps render correctly including the main website but visiting /app for some reason doesn't render correctly in terms of styling/layout.

I've tried to troubleshoot as much as I can including making sure Nginx can access and serve my static files but I can't figure out what the issue is. My tailwind css and static files render correctly on my website but not when I visit /app. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your collect static by running:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

then restart Uvicorn:

```
sudo systemctl restart uvicorn
```

Finally restart nginx server:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

This should fix the issue.
`

Comment: I tried this but I'm still not seeing any change. This only happens for mydomain/app.  What else can I try?

Comment: provide a link if publicly available. Or check the page source and compare with the page source where its working check href url for css,js. To me seems like might be linking issue from your app2 templates. @SimeonThomas

Comment: Yes, I found the error. It was related to a tailwind import in my file. Thanks for your help!